# Swift - Fetch photos from album in CollectionView and keep resolution

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView in which I load all of the user's photos from the photo album. All of the photos are fetched and stored in an array when the user opens the controller. Tapping a photo will create a subview with a black background and a bigger version of that photo. Tapping it again will remove it from the superView with a zoom-out transition.

My problem is that I don't know how to keep the original size of the photo as well as maintain a low execution time. Having 100+ photos load into a collection really hurts my load time.

I don't think it's necessary to fetch the pictures at a higher CGSize, because I actually want it to be the bounds of the cell (I have three cells per row).

**Fetching images at 250 by 250 returns a 0.20 second execution time**

**Fetching images at 300 by 300 returns a 3.0 seconds execution time**

What I want to achieve is to keep a very low execution time, have crisp thumbnails and a high resolution version of that photo when tapped. Do I have to create a second thread to load everything in the background or is it better to not call my function in my viewDidLoad?

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

func getPhotosFromAlbum() {

    let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

        if fetchResult.count > 0 {

            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {

                imageManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i), targetSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { image, error in

                    self.imageArray.append(image!)
                })
            }
        } else {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, if you are doing some heavy processing, it is better to do it in a background thread so that you don't lock up your main thread or make UI interaction sluggish. Of course, in that case, do remember to do any UI updates on the main thread. As an alternative to what you are doing, would caching the thumbnails make sense for what you want done? If yes, that might be an option you might want to explore since then you'd have most of the images you need already and would only need to fetch thumbnails for new images.

Comment: Thanks! I have added a background thread to load the pictures into my collectionView. I think it works fine now :-)

Comment: Great :) I have converted my comment to an answer. Please mark it as "correct" if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you are doing some heavy processing, it is better to do it in a background thread so that you don't lock up your main thread or make UI interaction sluggish. Of course, in that case, do remember to do any UI updates on the main thread.